# OneOdio Pro-10G Mic not working

Tags: sound, microphone

I recently bought the OneOdio Pro-10G headset.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the output (headphones) device is working properly, while the input (microphone) device is not being recognized and it fallbacks to the Internal (PC) microphone.

I’m sure the microphone is not broken since it works perfectly on Windows and Mac.

I already tried to follow a few given solutions found on the web but without success.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (run `lsb_release -a` the in terminal)
- Kernel version: 6.0.9-060009-generic (run `uname -r` in the terminal)

Audio settings:

[image: Audio settings]

Comment: You aren't using a *supported* Ubuntu 22.04 kernel, have you tried a *supported* Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: Maybe its not supported.

Comment: @guiverc I manually updated the kernel from a "supported" one in the hope of fixing the problem, but without success...

Comment: @RohitGupta Very probable. I hope there's a solution to that, otherwise I'll have to buy a new set of headphones.

Comment: You've grabbed a *testing* kernel I suspect, ie. all security fixes & patch responsibility is now yours to perform, so I hope you're aware of that & considered that in your decision.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has many *supported* kernels (GA, HWE, OEM options) but the *testing* kernels are built for testing, and aren't supported, so I suggest checking the *docs* where you obtained it  (ie. it may just require you manually updating your kernel from now on given you've *strayed* from the *supported* path). *You didn't say where it was from, but note https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds etc*